# Copying data to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy, find

I am having trouble understanding what the below function is doing.

The function itself has the ability to copy data to the sheet `Sheet History`. However, I do not get how it is doing it?

```
Sub histFunc()

Dim Y As String
Y = "R" & Range("G7").Value

    Sheets("Sheet History").Select
    Range("h17").Select

    Cells.Find(What:=Y, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Sheet Current").Select

End Sub
```

Any suggestions how this macro is operating?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

In short, the code searches for the value in *G7* in *Sheet History* and replaces the right part of that line with *values only*, i.e. removing references or values.

## Step-by-step Explanation

Get the value of cell G7:

```
Y = "R" & Range("G7").Value
```

Select sheet *Sheet History* and select cell *H17*:

```
Sheets("Sheet History").Select
Range("h17").Select
```

Executes the [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method over [`Cells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx), all cells in the sheet (note that if no parameter is given it is the range of all Cells in the current Sheet):

```
Cells.Find(What:=Y, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

This returns:

> A Range object that represents the first cell where that information is found.

For more info see the [`Find` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).
Now due to `.Activate` the (first) cell is selected where the value was found. This selection is extended to the end of the line:

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Then the `CutCopyMode` is deactivated to [clear the clipboard after usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607412/what-exactly-is-the-function-of-application-cutcopymode-property-in-excel):

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Now the selected cells are copied and pasted:

```
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Note that they are pasted on with [`PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) on the **same location**, using  [`xlPasteValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) to only maintain the values, and therefore not to have any formulas nor references in the cells.

Now go to *Sheet Current*:

```
Sheets("Sheet Current").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of cleaning, this is what this could look like (explanations below) :

```
Sub histFunc()
Dim FindRange As Range, _
    LookForValue As String
LookForValue = "R" & Range("G7").Value

With Sheets("Sheet History")
    .Range("h17").Activate
    Set FindRange = .Cells.Find(What:=LookForValue, _
                    After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range(FindRange, FindRange.End(xlToRight)).Copy
    FindRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                           Operation:=xlNone, _
                           SkipBlanks:=False, _
                           Transpose:=False
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Sheet Current").Select

End Sub
```

I changed `Y` to `LookForValue` for better understanding and used a Range variable to reference the result of the `Find` method.

So this code, step by step :

1. Define `LookForValue` as `"R" & Range("G7").Value`
2. Search for that value in the formulas of `Sheet History`
3. Copy the data block (in the row of the result, from result to right, until there is a blank)
4. Paste it at the same place but in *values*, so that you get rid of the formulas!